# MIPS - How to store the first 256 numbers in memory

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I have to write a program in assembly language that is to store in memory the first 256 integers from 0 to 255.

Here is the code I wrote (I am a beginner with the assembly language):

```
.data

memory: .space 256


.text

       li $t0, 0
       la $s0, memory
       sb $s0, 0($t0)

loop: 
       add $t0, $t0, 1
       sb $s0, 0($t0)
       j loop
```

I tried to run the program with SPIM but does not work: SPIM says there is an error to instruction `sb $s0, 0($t0)`.

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any code to break out of your loop, so you'll just keep on writing bytes forever, which eventually will result in a Bad Address exception.

You need to add some instructions in your loop that check if you have written 256 bytes, and if so *doesn't* jump back to `loop:`.

Another problem is that you've written the operands for `sb` in the wrong order. You want to store `$t0` at `$s0`, so it should be `sb $t0,0($s0)`. And you also need to increment `$s0` each time you increment `$t0`.

(Also, you should end your program by invoking syscall 10).

Comment: In `loop` I replaced `j loop` with `bne $t0, 256, loop` and I added this line `li $v0, 10` `syscall`, but I have the same error as before

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it seems to run correctly.